# Usando confirm() javascript com checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho essa linha que está dentro de um foreach:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="idAprovacao" name="idAprovacao" 
onclick="atualizaSituacao(<?php echo $resulta->id_aprovacao;?>);"
<?php echo ($resulta->in_situacao == "4") ? "checked disabled" : "" ?> value="">
```

E tenho essa função que faz com que exista a pergunta e se for aceita faz algo e se não DEVERIA desmarcar o checkbox, porém isso só acontece para o primeiro registro exibido.

```
function atualizaSituacao(id)
{
    confirma = window.confirm('Esse registro realmente foi lançado no SIGRH?');

    var idAprovacao = id;

    if(confirma == true) {    

    // acontece algo

    } else {    
        document.getElementById('idAprovacao').checked = false;
    }
}
```

O que está errado ou faltando?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Teoricamente, **um ID só deveria pertencer a 1 elemento**. Você possui vários elementos com `id="idAprovacao"`.
O comando `document.getElementById` **retorna apenas 1 elemento**, o primeiro que ele achar.
Portanto, você deve colocar um ID diferente para cada checkbox.

Na impressão do *input*, troque:
`id="idAprovacao"`
por:
`id="idAprovacao<?php echo $resulta->id_aprovacao;?>"`.

E no javascript, troque:
`document.getElementById('idAprovacao').checked = false;`
por:
`document.getElementById('idAprovacao'+id).checked = false;`

Comment: Mano, muito obrigado, eu sabia que era algo desse tipo mesmo, só não estava sabendo como realmente fazer. Perdi tempo tentando e resolvi vim aqui perguntar. Obrigado!

Comment: Tentando aproveitar a pergunta agora só para deixar melhor o que quero, como deixo para que na hora que marcar também ficar como disabled o mesmo checkbox?

Comment: `document.getElementById('idAprovacao'+id).disabled = true;`

Comment: Estava inventando coisa hahaha, mas tinha o .disabled então.. agora de boa. Valeu.! ;)